# llenar select con datos php y json

Tags: php, json, mysqli

hola tengo estos archivos conexion.php, get personal.php, getdata.js y configuración.
cuando pruebo todo por partes si funciona pero al unir la solucion no me da respuesta.
de hecho cuando quito lo que tiene que ver con get personal y demas, la pagina si funciona adecuadamente y el select primero me carga lo que está en la tabla, o si uso get personal por separado tambien me funciona adecuadamente, el detalle aqui es que no logro unir todo y que funcione adecuadamente
estos son mis codigos:
para conexion.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "oskar";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("La conexion ha fallado: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}


?>
para configuracion.php
    
    <?php
include 'conexion.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Inicio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="inde.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="assets/sticky-footer-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/getData.js"></script>
    <script>
        function toggle(o) {
        var el=document.querySelector(".masElementos");
        if (o.value=="marcas") el.style.display="block";
        if (o.value=="version") el.style.display="none";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menusup" >
        <button class="btn primary" onclick="location.href='buscar.php'">Buscar</button>
        <button class="btn secondary" onclick="location.href='agregar.php'">Agregar existencia</button>
        <button class="btn success" onclick="location.href='consultar.php'">Consultar</button>
        <button class="btn warning" onclick="location.href='modificar.php'">Modificar</button>
        <button class="btn danger" onclick="location.href='configuracion.php'">Configuración</button>
    </div>
    <div id="menudboton" >
        <select name="lenguajes" id="lang" onclick="toggle(this)">
        <option value="marcas">Marcas</option>
        <option value="version">Versión</option>
        <option value="proveedor">Proveedor</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="masElementos">
<label>Tipo:</label>
<select name="tipoPrestacion">
<option selected value="0" >--No seleccionado--</option>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT idMarca, mNombre FROM marca LIMIT 10";
$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) { 
?>
<option value="<?php echo $rows["idMarca"]; ?>"><?php echo $rows["mNombre"]; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
<label>Descripción:</label><textarea cols="45" name="desPrestacion"></textarea>
</div>
        <div id="display">
            <div class="row" id="heading" style="display:none;">
<br><h5>Resultados de la Base de Datos.</h5><br>           
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Nombre Empleado</th>
      <th scope="col">Edad</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td><div class="col-sm-4" id="emp_nombre"></div></td>
      <td><div class="col-sm-4" id="emp_edad"></div></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>   
</div>
            
<br>        
<div class="row" id="no_records">
            
<div class="col-sm-10">Por favor, seleccione el nombre del empleado para ver los detalles</div></div>
        </div>      
</div>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== --> 
<script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
</body>
</html>
```

este es para getpersonal.php es el agente externo que me permite conectar con la base de datos

```
    <?php
include_once("conexion.php");
if($_REQUEST['idMarca']) {
    $sql = "SELECT idVersion, vNombre FROM version WHERE idMarca='".$_REQUEST['idMarca']."'";
    $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
    
    $data = array();
    while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
        $data = $rows;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    echo 0; 
}
?>
```

este es para getdata.js este es el que lee los cambios en mi select

```
    $(document).ready(function(){  
    // code to get all records from table via select box
    $("#tipoPrestacion").change(function() {    
        var idMarc = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        var dataString = 'idMarca='+ idMarc;    
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getPersonal.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: dataString,  
            cache: false,
            success: function(marcaData) {
               if(marcaData) {
                    $("#heading").show();         
                    $("#no_records").hide();                    
                    $("#emp_nombre").text(marcaData.idVersion);
                    $("#emp_edad").text(marcaData.vNombre);

                    $("#records").show();        
                } else {
                    $("#heading").hide();
                    $("#records").hide();
                    $("#no_records").show();
                }       
            } 
        });
    }) 
});
```

espero y agradezco sus respuestas

Comment: hola , no veo cual es el problema o errror que te sale

Comment: El problema es que no funciona el script, no hace la función que haría si lo pruebo por partes

Comment: y como se supone que debemos encontrar el error??? soy malo adivinando